# Can a Facebook user know who views their profile/pics?

Tags: facebook

I want to know whether there is a way to tell who views my Timeline/Profile/pics on Facebook if we aren't friends.  Is there an app or a log or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no Facebook feature that enables you to see who viewed your information on Facebook, and to my knowledge there are no valid apps that enable you to do this either.  Beware of the many scams that go around Facebook from apps claiming they let you see who viewed your profile -- they're never valid.